# Checking mocks for equality

Tags: python, mocking

Is there an easy way to check two `unittest.mock.Mock` instances for equality based on their non-special attributes? `Mock` doesn't provide an `__eq__` implementation (and neither does `MagicMock` AFAIK), so `Mock(a=1) == Mock(a=1)` evaluates to `False`.

I'm looking for a solution that also works for nested mocks, i.e. for things like `Mock(a=Mock(x=1), b=2)`.

I've tried using `dir` to list the mocks' attributes, but that also contains special attributes like `method_calls`, which I want to ignore. I'm not a fan of hard-coding and removing the special attributes either.

To be precise, I'd like the following to return `True`:

```
m1 = Mock(a=1, b=Mock(c=2))
m2 = Mock(a=1, b=Mock(c=2))
m1.some_method()
compare_mocks(m1, m2)
```

Whereas the following should return `False` (different value of `.b.c`):

```
compare_mocks(Mock(a=1, b=Mock(c=2)), Mock(a=1, b=Mock(c=3))
```

Comment: Could you define what you mean by their "non-special attributes"?

Comment: @wim: I only want to compare attributes that my code has set on the mocks, but not those attributes (like `method_calls`) which the `mock` library automatically provides.

Comment: Why wouldn't mutable state such as the mock's call count be considered as part of any reasonable definition of equality for mock instances? I'm not sure I understand the use case here.

Comment: @wim: Depending on the use case there are probably different, equally valid approaches to defining mock equality. In my case, all that counts are the non-special attributes, so that's what I'm after. For example, I don't care which methods were called on the mock as long as its final state is correct. It's like comparing two dicts: Do you care whether one was constructed by passing an iterable to the constructor and the other via `__setitem__`? You probably don't, as long as they map the same keys to the same values.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `MagicMock` instead of `Mock`(https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#magicmock-and-magic-method-support) because `MagicMock` supports magic methods including the `__eq__` method. Then, you will be able to use the `==` operator for comparing `MagicMock` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything except brute-force checking the attributes.

```
def mock_attrs_eq(m1, m2):
    new = type(m1)()
    m1_dir = sorted(set(dir(m1)) - set(dir(new)))
    m2_dir = sorted(set(dir(m2)) - set(dir(new)))
    if len(m1_dir) != len(m2_dir):
        return False
    for name1, name2 in zip(m1_dir, m2_dir):
        if name1 != name2:
            return False
        attr1 = getattr(m1, name1)
        attr2 = getattr(m2, name2)
        typenames = {attr1.__class__.__name__, attr2.__class__.__name__}
        if typenames == {new.__class__.__name__}:
            if not mock_attrs_eq(attr1, attr2):
                return False
        else:
            if attr1 != attr2:
                return False
    return True
```

This should meet your requirements for simple use-cases.
In the case that one mock actually references the other, this may go into infinite recursion.

Comment: I don't see how this ignores special attributes like `method_calls` -- if you call a method on one of the mocks but not on the other then they compare as unequal even if their other attributes are equal.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker  Worked for me. Make a reproducible example, please.

Comment: I've added an example which fails for me for your code (your code returns `False` in the first comparison).

Comment: @FlorianBrucker The action of using `m1.some_method()` actually *creates* a new attribute `some_method` on `m1` which is not present on `m2`. It's not returning false because of the content in `method_calls`, it's returning false because `m1` has a "non-special" attribute that is not on `m2`. So, your requirement to return `True` there is in conflict with the requirement "*equality based on their non-special attributes*". One of these requirements has to go.